# Does pure silicon conduct electricity?

Tags: current, semiconductors

I understand that silicon has an incredibly important use in microelectronics, as its semi-conductive properties allow us to make transistors. However, this is only possible after introducing other elements such as phosphorus and boron into the lattice. What I'm wondering is if silicon is able to conduct electricity at all without any doping being done?

Comment: Question can be answered in a few seconds with a Google search.

Comment: Pure silicon has two interesting properties:  very poor conductivity and a very well known crystal structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

they all conduct electricity to some degree, some more than others, as a perfect insulator doesn't exist.

the resistivity data for silicon is widely available. on the order of Kohm x m, vs. nohm x m for copper. that should give you some sense of its conductivity.

Answer (score 3):

Silicon is an insulator and all insulators are dielectrics.

In this case it conducts about the same as water but far more than than deionized water and much less than sea water.

All insulators conduct to some extent due to contaminants with DC

and all dielectrics conduct with AC.